# How does Land's Stride interact with Plant Growth?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, druid

Circle of the Land Druids gain the Land's Stride ability one level after the ability to cast Plant Growth. How do these two interact with respect to movement?

A good answer will explain in detail how Plant Growth works in order to address the "non-magical plants" part of Land's Stride.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Plant Growth

> There are two possible uses.  If you cast this spell using 1 Action, ... all normal plants in a 100-foot radius become thick and overgrown.  A creature moving through the area must spend 4 feet of movement for every 1 foot it moves..."

### Land's Stride

> "...moving through nonmagical difficult terrain costs you no extra movement.  You can also pass through nonmagical plants without being slowed by them and without taking damage from them if they have thorns, spines, or similar hazards... In addition, you have advantage....against plants that are magically created or manipulated to impede movement..."

Well then, this one is a little tricky.  First and most importantly, *"Plant Growth"* does not actually create **Difficult Terrain** with its spell effect, nor does it create magical plants, vines, thorns, etc.  It does, however, cause naturally occuring plants to become so overgrown that it impedes or otherwise slows anyone moving through the area, with a magical effect.

When we look at *Land's Stride* we see that moving through nonmagical difficult terrain will costs you no extra movement.  Since this is **not** difficult terrain, however, this first part does not apply when you move through the effected area of *Plant Growth*.  Then we see that "You can also pass through nonmagical plants without being slowed" , which is where the synergy comes in to play.  Since *Plant Growth* uses magic to cause mundane nonmagical plants and vegetation to overgrow and effect your movement, *Land's Stride* allows you to move through these plants without being affected.  Lastly, since 'Plant Growth' does not offer you a saving throw for you **to** have Advantage against, the last part of *Land's Stride* also does not apply here, but it IS important to note that "plants that are magically manipulated to impede movement" is precisely what Plant Growth is doing, even if the plants themselves are nonmagical in nature.

Comment: A good analysis.  I have to wonder, though, if you cast the spell and all plants within 100 feet become overgrown, does that mean you're stuck in the middle of your own trap and have to spend 400 feet of movement to get out?

Comment: @MasonWheeler If you don't have an ability like Land's Stride to circumvent the movement decrease, there are two options: 1. the range is any spot within 150ft to place the 100 foot area of overgrowth, that gives you quite a bit of room to avoid it. and 2. "..You can exclude one or more areas of any size within the spells area from being affected" , which means you could make a little path for you and your friends, or simply choose any section they / you are standing in to be unaffected.  I discluded that part because it wasn't relevant to the main question though.

Comment: I fail to understand a plant that is magically enhanced is not treated as magical while the spell is in effect.   If you are the receiver of an enlarge spell, you are actually detecting as magical are you not ?

Comment: @KilrathiSly - Note that Plant Growth doesn't have a duration in the non 8-hour cast. So the magical effect is the rapid growth, but once they've grown, they remain that large forever. There is no magical effect forcing them to remain large. Enlarge/reduce is over after a minute, so there is a magical force keeping like that.